# Property of involutory matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A=A^{-1}$ for some matrix $A$, which is not the identity matrix. Then prove the trace of the matrix is equal to its determinant.

I have shown the determinant can only be $+1$ or $-1$. Also as for any eigenvalue of $A$ , it's square is the eigenvalue of $A^2$, it also holds that all the eigenvalue of $A$ are either $1$ or $-1$. I also know that trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues but I can't still prove the rest. Please help.

Comment: Hint: The characteristic polynomial of a matrix $B$ is $p(X) = X^d + (\operatorname{trace}B)X^{d-1} + \ldots + \det B$.

Comment: Are you preparing for IIT-JEE

Answer (score 2):

The statment is not true. Take $A=I$ (A is identity matrix, 2 x 2), so $A=A^{−1}$. Trace is equal to $2$ and the determinant is $1$.

Comment: I forgot to mention the property is to be proven for non identity involutory matrices. I have edited the question now.

Comment: $A=-I$ also can't be. right?

Comment: This question must be better explained, because there is a group of matrix that suit the problem. Examples: $A=I$, $A=-I$, $A=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, $A=\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.

Comment: Actually if we consider a higher dimension we get a lot of matrix that suit the problem. In order to do that, choose the identity matrix and changing the signal of the numbers in the diagonal.